# CKEditor: how to remove a plugin that has been added?

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I'm just beginning to use CKEditor, but have a hard time understanding the plugins system.

I was able to add a simple button that says 'Test' when you click on it with :

```
  var myplugin_function = function () {
    alert('Test');
  }
  var plugin_name='myplugin';
  CKEDITOR.plugins.add(plugin_name,   
  {    
    init:function(c) {
      c.addCommand(plugin_name,myplugin_function);
      c.ui.addButton(plugin_name, 
      {
       label:'This is my plugin',
       command:plugin_name,
       icon:this.path+'myplugin.png'
      });
    }
  });
```

I know this code should be executed only once, for example in a `plugin.js`, but that's not how I use it. The CKEditor instance, including my plugin code is executed each time the Ajax-page is loaded.

That's why I use this to remove the instance, if it exists :

```
  if (CKEDITOR.instances['mytextarea']) {
    CKEDITOR.remove(CKEDITOR.instances['mytextarea']);
  }
```

Then I use the jquery way to create the ckeditor from a textarea:

```
$('#mytextarea').ckeditor();
```

But the 2nd time the ajax-page loads, I get an error about the plugin already being registered. So I need a way to remove the plugin and be able to add it *again*.

Is this even possible?

***UPDATE***

This seems to work :

I now check if the plugin is already registered with :

```
if (!CKEDITOR.plugins.registered[plugin_name]) {

}
```

around the `CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b,`   ... part

Comment: Your update stops the error but my button does not work the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing how you are adding the plugin, so it's hard to tell what's your exact problem; but from the code that you have provided I can suggest that you use variable names better than "a", "b" and "c". It's quite harder to understand the code this way.

Also, [CKEDITOR.remove](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.remove) just removes the instance from the instances array, but it doesn't really clear the used resources, you should use CKEDITOR.instances['mytextarea'].[destroy( true )](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#destroy) instead

Comment: ok thanks, that explains why FF is slowing down a lot after a few uses of the page, I guess...

Comment: destroying instances does not remove plugins that were added in code